# How to make VoiceOver work when the input view is moving

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, voiceover

I have an iPad app that presents a UITextField inside a UIPopover when a button is tapped. This button is near the bottom of the screen. So, the user taps the button, the popover appears and becomes the first responder, which causes the keyboard to appear. This, in turn, causes the popover to move up as the keyboard slides in. This works fine, except for VoiceOver.

It appears that VoiceOver gets confused by the moving view. It starts to describe the new text field, but then stops mid-word as soon as it starts to move.

Does anyone know of a good work-around. The best I've come up with so far is to listen for UIKeyboardDidShowNotification and then find some way to kick VoiceOver to talk again, though I'm not sure how to kick VoiceOver into action.

Comment: I discovered that I was calling becomeFirstResponder on the text field being presented in the content view controller's viewDidLoad method. Switching to calling becomeFirstResponder in the viewDidAppear: method seems to have made the problem go away. This may not be a general solution to similar problems, but it is a working workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can inform VoiceOver of changes to your screen layout by using the accessibility notifications - UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification or UIAcessibilityScreenChangedNotification would be good candidates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Unfortunately, it seems that it does not cause VoiceOver to tell the current control if VoiceOver thinks it just said that one. I can switch focus to something else with these, wait for it to start talking, then switch back, but that's a pretty bad hack.

Comment: @c-had I know that the `UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently` trait will cause VoiceOver to read the label of the selected element every few seconds as it changes (think for example of a stopwatch) but I don't know if it will also update the frame of that element.